# Django: 'User' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'

Tags: django

I'm analyzing a SignUp View for learning purposes.

I want to understand if the SignUp View could be improved. It works now, but could it be improved?

For example, if I use:

```
username = user.cleaned_data.get('username')
```

Instead of:

```
username = user_form.cleaned_data.get('username')
```

I get this errror:

```
'User' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'
```

Why?

**SignUp View:**

```
@transaction.atomic
def signupView(request):
    ###
   peru = Peru.objects.all()
   department_list = set()
   province_list = set()
   district_list = set()
   for p in peru:
     department_list.add(p.departamento)
     department_list = list(department_list)
   if len(department_list):
       province_list = set(Peru.objects.filter(departamento=department_list[0]).values_list("provincia", flat=True))
    province_list = list(province_list)
   else:
       province_list = set()
   if len(province_list):
        district_list = set(
        Peru.objects.filter(departamento=department_list[0], provincia=province_list[0]).values_list("distrito",
                                                                                                     flat=True))
   else:
      district_list = set()


    if request.method == 'POST':

        print("SIGNUP REQUEST POST: ", request.POST)
        #####

        peru = Peru.objects.all()
        department_list = set()
        province_list = set()
        district_list = set()
        for p in peru:
            department_list.add(p.departamento)
        department_list = list(department_list)

        if len(department_list):
            province_list = set(
                Peru.objects.filter(departamento__in=department_list).values_list("provincia", flat=True))

            province_list = list(province_list)

        else:
            province_list = set()
        if len(province_list):
            district_list = set(
                Peru.objects.filter(departamento__in=department_list, provincia__in=province_list).values_list(
                    "distrito",
                    flat=True))

        else:
            district_list = set()

        #####



        user_form = SignUpForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(district_list, province_list, department_list, request.POST, request.FILES)

        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_active = False
            user.save()
            username = user_form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            signup_user = User.objects.get(username=username)
            customer_group = Group.objects.get(name='Clientes')
            customer_group.user_set.add(signup_user)
            raw_password = user_form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user.refresh_from_db()  # This will load the Profile created by the Signal

            profile_form = ProfileForm(district_list, province_list, department_list, request.POST, request.FILES,
                                       instance=user.profile)  # Reload the profile form with the profile instance
            profile_form.full_clean()  # Manually clean the form this time. It is implicitly called by "is_valid()" method


            print("Profile Cleaned Data: ", profile_form.cleaned_data)
            profile_form.save()  # Gracefully save the form

            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)

            return redirect('carrito_de_compras:cart_detail')

        else:
            print(user_form.errors)
            print(profile_form.errors)

    else:

        user_form = SignUpForm()

        profile_form = ProfileForm(district_list, province_list, department_list)


    return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html', {
        'user_form': user_form,
        'profile_form': profile_form
    })
```

**Bonus:**

```
 profile_form = ProfileForm(district_list, province_list, department_list, request.POST, request.FILES)
```

is before

```
if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
```

but also after it. Is it correct?

**forms.py**:

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    error_messages = {
        'password_mismatch': "Las contraseñas no coinciden.",
    }

    first_name = forms.CharField(label="Nombre", max_length=100, required=True)
    last_name = forms.CharField(label='Apellido', max_length=100, required=True)
    username = forms.CharField(label='Nombre de usuario', max_length=100, required=True,
                               error_messages={'invalid': "you custom error message"})
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Correo electrónico', max_length=60, required=True)
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Contraseña', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Confirmar contraseña', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SignUpForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for fieldname in ['username', 'password1', 'password2']:
            self.fields[fieldname].help_text = None

    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                self.error_messages['password_mismatch'],
                code='password_mismatch',
            )
        return password2


    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email', 'password1',
                  'password2')




class ProfileForm(ModelForm):
    MONTHS = {
        1:'ene', 2:'feb', 3:'mar', 4:'abr',
        5:'may', 6:'jun', 7:'jul', 8:'ago',
        9:'set', 10:'oct', 11:'nov', 12:'dic'
    }

    def __init__(self, district_list, province_list, department_list, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['shipping_district'] = forms.ChoiceField(label='Distrito', choices=tuple([(name, name) for name in district_list]))
        self.fields['shipping_province'] = forms.ChoiceField(label='Provincia', choices=tuple([(name, name) for name in province_list]))
        self.fields['shipping_department'] = forms.ChoiceField(label='Departamento', choices=tuple([(name, name) for name in department_list]))


    dni = forms.CharField(label='DNI', max_length=100, required=True)
    phone_number = forms.CharField(label='Celular')
    birthdate = forms.DateField(label='Fecha de nacimiento', widget=SelectDateWidget(years=range(1980, 2012), months=MONTHS))
    shipping_address1 = forms.CharField(label='Dirección de envío', max_length=100, required=True)
    address_reference = forms.CharField(label='Referencia', max_length=100, required=False)
    photo = forms.ImageField(label='Foto de perfil', required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('dni', 'phone_number', 'birthdate', 'shipping_address1',
                  'address_reference', 'shipping_department', 'shipping_province', 'shipping_district', 'photo')
```

**models.py:**

```
### User Profile ###

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    birthdate = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    dni = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    shipping_address1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    address_reference = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    shipping_department = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    shipping_province = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    shipping_district = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics', default='profile_pics/default_profile_pic_white.png')


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user.first_name) + "'s profile"




@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
    instance.profile.save()
```

Comment: Instead of having 2 forms and a signal, why don't you use one form with both user and profile fields, and save them in a same `save()` method?

Comment: @ruddra saw this on a tutorial, but if there is a better way (less code) please, share.

Comment: Please share your code regarding forms and models which you have used for this implementation :)

Comment: @ruddra see updated code regarding forms and models. ty-.

Answer (score 1):

"user" is the instance of the User model, it doesn't have cleaned_data. Only the form has that attribute.